# Using VS Code to Build Project from Source to Executable

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to familiarize myself with Visual Studio Code and the process of semi-automatically building code. So far I've configured VS Code to the point where it can build a [C++] project successfully, but it doesn't generate an executable that can be debugged. What would the next step after successfully compiling a project be?

My build task looks like this:

```
"label": "build ArrayList (gnu)",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args":
        [
            "-g",
            "-c",
            "-Wall",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\sauce\\ArrayList.h",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\sauce\\ArrayTest.cpp",
            "-std=c++0x"
        ],
        "options":
        {
            "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
        },
        "group":
        {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
```

Comment: Is your c++ project a library(doesn't have a main and is used by other programs) or is it a program? in the first case, you will get a .dll/.so/.dylib based on the platform and in the second case you can expect an executable or a .o

Comment: If you are developing a library then a good way to debug would be to write some tests with it which you can use to debug

Comment: I have not determined how to specify which to build it as.